# JQuery UI - tabs (# and local doc links) + two accodrions - not showing first accordion when other tab reloaded

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, accordion

it's difficult to search or explain the problem, but i'll try

basically i have jquery tabs defined:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#Summary" title="Summary">Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="content.php?div=Products" title="Products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="login.php" title="Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Summary" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="font-size: 85%;" align="center">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

in Summary tab i have two accordions defined:

```
<td id="product_summary" valign="top" align="center">
    <div id="release_info" style="display: block; width: 99%;" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
        <h3>General Information</h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>

        <h3>Description information</h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td id="" style="width: 280px;" valign="top" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="controls" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"><a href="#">Search</a></h3>
        <div class="ui-accordion-content">
            ....
        </div>

        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header"><a href="#">Controls</a></h3>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

in the head of the document i have them defined as:

```
$(function() {
    $("#controls, #release_info").accordion({
       active: 0,
       heightStyle: "fill",
       autoHeight: false,            
       navigation: true,            
       collapsible: true,
       create: function(event, ui) { $("#controls, #release_info").show(); }
    });
    $('#controls').accordion({
       width: 280,
    });

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        cache: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
        }
    });
});
```

when i load page on Summary tab, where accordions defined - everything is as expected. But if i'm on Products tab (link to content.php) reload data - only second accordion is showing full length of of the page.

as you can see i'm using cache for tabs so i'm guessing i should somehow activate accordions again when navigating back to Summary tab. `Summary tab = index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer needed any more

The problem was caused by 3rd party colResizable plug in. Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

first make tabs 
by

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

then in tabs make accordian

```
 $("#" + accordionID).accordion();
```

then it will work